# unix find command

Tags: unix, shell

how to use the find command to find files/directories which are not matching the pattern.
for eg:

```
find <some options > -name "dontfile.txt"
```

should give me output of all the find whose file name is not  `dontfile.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find <some options> ! -name "dontfile.txt"
```

this should be the answer.
thanks Dave.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-not` operator:

```
find <some options > -not -name "dontfile.txt"
```

You may need to add parenthesis to get the desired effect, depending on how complex the rest of the command is:

```
find <some options > \( -not -name "dontfile.txt" \)
```

Comment: not sure whether this will work.i am working on hpux and its not accepting the `-not` option

Comment: On HPUX, use `!`. http://www.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/doc/man/hpux/find.1.html

Comment: Try ! instead of -not - i.e. find <some options> ! -name "dontfile.txt"

Answer (score -2):

$ ls -ltr

total 0

-rw-r--r--    1 mraj     baudba          0 Nov 18 05:35 d.txt

-rw-r--r--    1 mraj     baudba          0 Nov 18 05:35 c.txt

-rw-r--r--    1 mraj     baudba          0 Nov 18 05:35 b.txt

-rw-r--r--    1 mraj     baudba          0 Nov 18 05:35 a.txt

$ find . -name "a.txt" -print

./a.txt

$ find . ! -name "a.txt" -print

.

./b.txt

./c.txt

./d.txt

$

[Unix find command with examples](http://www.scripterworld.com/2009/07/unix-find-command-with-examples-and.html)

Comment: @bhagya..this is same as the above one ..i cannot find any difference.